# Strange position of the page after loading it

Tags: javascript, ajax, pageload

Why is it that every time when I load my site it is not opening as every page, but in the middle, so I have to scroll up to see top of this page.

I know it's because Ajax-based chatbox, but I cannot spot where it's wrong.
JavaScript is included at the bottom of the page, before `</body>`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you'll need to show some code. Is the chatbox from a library you can name?

Comment: Perhaps the URL has a #foo linking to a simple `<a name="foo" />` somewhere on the page? If not, please give **details** about the problem — perhaps a link to the site or at least some code.

Comment: A live demo of the issue please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 120 of the script output by chat.php has this line:

```
message.focus();
```

Which is giving focus to the `<input id="message" type="text" size="25" maxlength="80"  onkeyup="keyup(event);">` text input. That's what's jumping your page down.

It jumps down to that point and **then** loads the chat messages.

Answer (score 0):

Your index2.html has loads of `<br>` tags; which is the spacing gap you see.

```
<html> 
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css"> 
</head> 
<body> 
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> 
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> 
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> 
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> 
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> 

<div id="chatramka"> 
<div style="text-align:center;margin:3px;">Shoutbox</div> 
    <div id="chat">Åadowanie shoutboxa...</div>     
    <div style="overflow:auto;"><input id="message" type="text" size="25" maxlength="80"  onkeyup="keyup(event);"> 
    <input id="chatbtn" type="button" value="wyÅ›lij" onclick="chat_write();" style="cursor:pointer;border:1px solid gray;"></div> 
</div> 
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="chat.php"></script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: i still dont see, why it is opening on the middle of the page

Comment: do not use br for break use margin